# select longtext column too slow in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table like below,

```
CREATE TABLE `floor` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `floorName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `buildingId` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `imageInString` longtext,
  `image` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_floor_1_idx` (`buildingId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_floor_1` FOREIGN KEY (`buildingId`) REFERENCES `building` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

table contains 20 rows. I am inserting images(SVG/JPEG) as base64 in the **image** column.

when I select different size of inserted column it takes,

```
4KB -> Loaded less than 1 sec

200KB -> 3 to 4 secs

500KB -> 8 secs

3MB   -> 30 to 50 secs
```

Here is my dealing, I want to load the 3MB file in 1 to 2 secs.

How can achieve this?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, MySQL should be able to read that column in less than a second, so the actual reason might be something different, but it is hard to diagnose. If it's temporary, it might be heavy disk i/o or server load. If not: try `select id from floor where image like '%20%'`. This should give you the time mysql needs to read/process that column (for all 20 rows). If that's fast, your problem very likely lies somewhere else (than included in your question), e.g. a slow connection, the way you process the value (slow decode function, reading the resultset slowly in php, ...), ...

Comment: What is in the other `LONGTEXT`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will be a good idea to store images in MySQL - it's not built to store files, or large files for that matter.
To avoid this pattern, I would recommend to store the images on a web server / in the cloud and just store the url / file name in the database, for the application's use.

If you would like to store the images in the database anyway, I would consider the following:

1. Try different data types - what happens if you change the column type to BLOB and save binary information?
2. Check for network connectivity - it's easier to say than do. Therefore, I would start with running your query locally on the MySQL server and not from a different server. That way, you can avoid the network lag and see which part takes longer, transferring the image over the network or uploading it to the database.

Comment: Changing to `BLOB` (and not using base64) would shrink the amount of storage needed by 6/8.  However, the escaping needed might lead to more network traffic.